# SQL insert prepared statement not working but update does

Tags: php, web, prepared-statement

I've the following php code

```
   $riziv = $_GET["riziv"];
   $answer1 = (int)$_GET["answer1"];
   $answer2 = (int)$_GET["answer2"];
   $name = $_get["name"];
   $first_name = $_get["first_name"];
   $city = $_get["city"];

   if (empty($riziv)) {
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Doctors 
                 (name,first_name,city,answer1,answer2) 
                 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
       $stmt->bind_param("sssdd",$name,$first_name,$city,$answer1,$answer2);
   }else{
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE Doctors SET answer1 = ?, answer2 = ? WHERE riziv=?");
       $stmt->bind_param("dds",$answer1,$answer2,$riziv);
   }

   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();

   $this->db->commit();
```

The update is working but the insert breaks on the bind_param line?
Can anybody help?

Thanks !

Comment: `$_GET`, not `$_get` - it's case-sensitive

Comment: What about checking `$stmt->errorInfo();` ?

Comment: stupid case-sensitive ... Thanks @MarkBaker